# How to lookup and match the the certain value from different data frame in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem when I want to create new columns right after this column, in the same dataframe :

```
print(df["Title"])
0                                           Others
1                                           Others
2                          Some major design flaws
3                                 My favorite buy!
4                                 Flattering shirt
5                          Not for the very petite
6                             Cagrcoal shimmer fun
7             Shimmer, surprisingly goes with lots
8                                       Flattering
9                                Such a fun dress!
10    Dress looks like it's made of cheap material
Name: Title, dtype: object
```

I tried to figure out the positive comments from the sentences and here's what I got :

```
title_words=df["Title"].str.strip().str.lower().replace("","").str.strip('!.,?').str.split(expand=True).stack()

#print(words)
pos_title=title_words[title_words.isin(df2["Words"])]
print(pos_title)
```

and here's the result :

```
print(pos_title)
3   1      favorite
4   0    flattering
6   2           fun
8   0    flattering
9   2           fun
10  2          like
dtype: object
```

The objective is to create a new column, matching the index number from the first column "Title" with the result of the pos_title. If there's a sentence which is not containing the positive word (or pos_title, in this case), it should be left "None".

This is the expected output :

[image]

How should I code? Your helps would be very appreciated, since I'm new to Python. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to check in the original dataframe rather than splitting it out.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
titles =  {'Title': [
    'Others',
    'Others',
    'Some major design flaws',
    'My favorite buy!',
    'Flattering shirt',
    'Not for the very petite',
    'Cagrcoal shimmer fun',
    'Shimmer, surprisingly goes with lots',
    'Flattering',
    'Such a fun dress!',
    'Dress looks like it\'s made of cheap material'
]}

pos_words = {"Words":[
    'favorite',
    'flattering',
    'fun',
    'like']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(titles)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(pos_words)

pos_words = list(df2["Words"])
df['positive'] = (
        df.Title.str.
        findall('|'.join(pos_words), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        )
```

This returns a dataframe like so:

```
       |                                Title         | positive     |
0      |                                   Others     |        []    |
1      |                                  Others      |          []  |
2      |                 Some major design flaws      |          []  |
3      |                        My favorite buy!      |  [favorite]  |
4      |                        Flattering shirt      | [Flattering] |
5      |                  Not for the very petite     |          []  |
6      |                     Cagrcoal shimmer fun     |       [fun]  |
7      |     Shimmer, surprisingly goes with lots     |          []  |
8      |                               Flattering     | [Flattering] |
9      |                        Such a fun dress!     |       [fun]  |
10     | Dress looks like it's made of cheap material |   [like]     |
```

findall() returns a series of matches, and hence the brackets. If you had multiple matches in a single strng for instance "My favorite,  flattering fun shirt that I like" it would return [favorite, flattering, fun, like] for that string.

If you append astype('str') and a replace function, you can then remove the potentially unwanted brackets and quotes.

```
df['positive'] = (
    df.Title.str
    .findall('|'.join(pos_words), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    .astype(str)
    .replace('\]', "", regex=True)
    .replace('\,', "", regex=True)
    .replace('\'', "", regex=True)
    .replace('\[', "", regex=True)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I tried your code and it's not working. The dataframe2 or df2["Words"] contains the collection of positive words, that I used to lookup to. Here, I just want to create the new columns in the df (not in df2), matching up the output of pos_title and df["Title"], just like the expected output shown above.

Comment: @dhika91 I edited in response to your changes. Just as an FYI always helpful to specify what exactly is not working (for instance did you get an error code, if so what was it, was the data type not as you expected, etc.)

Comment: Yeah it's working ! Thank you for your complete explanation, really helpful!